# does clisp (Ubuntu port) has indent and parenthese completion

Tags: common-lisp, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop, clisp

`clisp interpreter` come from `Ubuntu package` is very good with `readline`, editing single line of code is easy.  Though work it with `Slime` most time it make me think if it's possible to get `auto-indent` and `parentheses flashing/completion` in `clisp interpreter` itself.

EDIT: 
`(ED "FILE.NAME.LISP")` can call system editor, and start editing, the results will not AUTO loaded into the REPL.

Comment: Do you mean the REPL with "clisp interpreter"?

Answer (score 1):

1. clisp does flash back to matching paren as long as you stay on a single line. This limitation stems from readline which provides the feature.
2. clisp does not auto-indent on console.
3. the editor does not auto-load the edited file because your edit might be unsuccessful; you should try to compile the file first to uncover the errors.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: (ED "FILE.NAME.LISP") can call system editor, and start editing,
>   the results will not AUTO loaded into the REPL.

You can easily write a function that will call up your editor then load the file when you're done with it.

Something like this in your `.clisprc.lisp`, for example:

```
(defun edit-load-file (filename)
   (ed filename)
   (load filename))
```